# Can i catch a line number of xml on javax.xml.bind.MarshalException?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb, marshalling

I have other error like this, ther's a way to get in output the field of object not validated??

cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '02' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.

```
public static String marshalValidatingBoPgit(Object el) throws Exception {
    if (el == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Marshaller m = JaxbContextHolder.getInstance().getMarshaller(XmlObject.class);
    m.setSchema(SchemaManager.getSchema("idb/xmlXsd/xml-schema.xsd"));
    m.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
            System.err.println(event);
            return false;
        }
    });
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    m.marshal(el, baos);
    baos.flush();
    String result = new String(baos.toByteArray());
    baos.close();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: wel, '02' is not the same as '2'. the error is pretty straight forward.

Comment: Yes but it's a big xml with other enumeration like this, so.. no way to found de line number, or tag Name of XmlObject.class?